# GTK application randomly segfaults

Tags: segmentation-fault, gtk, glib

I'm making an IRC application in GTK. The application runs fine for an extended period of time. Then it will randomly segfault. It happens regardless of if I am interacting with the application or not. It also seems to happen independently of what the application is doing. It appears to be a random signal that causes the segfault. I think this is the case because g_signal_emit_valist is at the top of the backtrace.

I installed the debugging symbols and captured a backtrace. This is really hard to track down because it seems like something GTK does in the background. It happens randomly and the user does not need to be interacting with the application at all:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911654] [Gtk] gtk_container_get_path_for_child: assertion 'container == (GtkContainer *) gtk_widget_get_parent (child)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911685] Relay will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911711] [Gtk] gtk_widget_path_length: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911727] Relay will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911751] [Gtk] gtk_widget_path_length: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911765] Relay will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911787] [Gtk] _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911802] Relay will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911822] [Gtk] gtk_widget_path_free: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911837] Relay will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911857] [Gtk] _gtk_css_array_value_get_n_values: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 23:35:03.911872] Relay will not function properly.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff68511d5 in _gtk_css_computed_values_get_difference (values=values@entry=0x11ecd80, other=other@entry=0x7e1360) at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkcsscomputedvalues.c:265
265 /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkcsscomputedvalues.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff68511d5 in _gtk_css_computed_values_get_difference (values=values@entry=0x11ecd80, other=other@entry=0x7e1360) at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkcsscomputedvalues.c:265
#1  0x00007ffff69844dd in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=0xde7140, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=2056, change@entry=GTK_CSS_CHANGE_PARENT_STATE, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x152d200)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3077
#2  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=GTK_CSS_CHANGE_PARENT_STATE, change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#3  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#4  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#5  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#6  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#7  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#8  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#9  0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#10 0x00007ffff69843d2 in _gtk_style_context_validate (context=<optimized out>, timestamp=timestamp@entry=42210631858, change=change@entry=0, parent_changes=parent_changes@entry=0x1)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:3115
#11 0x00007ffff684b5ba in gtk_container_idle_sizer (clock=0x6b2200, container=0x884230) at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gtk/gtkcontainer.c:1738
#12 0x00007ffff5c563f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff5c6e728 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff5c6f8a2 in g_signal_emit_by_name () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff6486642 in gdk_frame_clock_paint_idle (data=0x6b2200) at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gdk/gdkframeclockidle.c:408
#16 0x00007ffff6478e08 in gdk_threads_dispatch (data=0x12fa640) at /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.14.13/./gdk/gdk.c:656
#17 0x00007ffff59834d3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff5982ab5 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff5982e18 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
```

Here is one backtrace:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6870a85 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6870a85 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff6851240 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff69844dd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff684b5ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#14 0x00007ffff5c563f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff5c6e728 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff5c6f8a2 in g_signal_emit_by_name () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff6486642 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff6478e08 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff59834d3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff5982ab5 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff5982e18 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff59830da in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff68f2675 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#24 0x00000000004335b2 in relay_real_activate (base=0x656200) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:158
#25 0x00007ffff5c563f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff5c6e728 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff5c6f372 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#28 0x00007ffff61871df in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff618737b in g_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff753e0c0 in granite_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgranite.so.2
#31 0x0000000000433461 in relay_main (args=0x7fffffffe088, args_length1=2) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:123
#32 0x000000000043349e in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe088) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:132
```

Here is another one which has an odd CSS error in the log before it segfaults. I am not doing anything with CSS:

```
    [_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 13:22:40.458929] [Gtk] _gtk_css_array_value_get_n_values: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 13:22:40.458954] Relay will not function properly.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff68511d5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff68511d5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff69844dd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff69843d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff684b5ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff5c563f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff5c6e728 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#14 0x00007ffff5c6f8a2 in g_signal_emit_by_name () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff6486642 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff6478e08 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff59834d3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff5982ab5 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff5982e18 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff59830da in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff68f2675 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#22 0x00000000004334a7 in relay_real_activate (base=0x656200) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:158
#23 0x00007ffff5c563f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff5c6e728 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff5c6f372 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff61871df in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff618737b in g_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff753e0c0 in granite_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgranite.so.2
#29 0x000000000043335d in relay_main (args=0x7fffffffe088, args_length1=2) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:123
#30 0x000000000043339a in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe088) at /home/kyle/Apps/projects/relay/src/relay.c:132
```

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you with that.  Install the relevant debugging symbols (for gtk+, gdk, and glib) and you *might* have better luck.  Try running your program in valgrind.

Comment: It sounds like a memory corruption issue most likely caused by your code rather than Gtk, run your program in valgrind and see if it gives any better indication of where corruption might be.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was happening because I was calling a signal out of the main UI thread. Once I wraped Idle() around it the issue went away.